# Is there a way to review past error messages?

Tags: python, spyder, moviepy

I have a Python script that I use through Spyder to combine video files into one. I've used it quite a few times before. I do make minor changes to it now and then, but nothing that should have cause a major malfunction. It does however hog most of my machine's resources. Anyway, its supposed to iterate through a ton of files and write several new video files, and just now after it got through making 1 video and started on the next, it hung for a second, and briefly threw an error that said something along the lines of not being able to read the first frame of one of my input files, and then all my screens went black, and I had to hard reboot. I have no idea which file it threw the error on, or if that was even the actual cause, there are hundreds of files it goes through. Is there a way of finding it?

Answer (score 1):

The past error messages are stored if the logger is activated. Find the log file location in the system. If you are using linux then it might be in the home folder hidden somewhere. In windows you can find it in C drive system folder.